# Diesel: Query most recent row of data, per group

Tags: rust, rust-diesel, rust-diesel-mysql

A common SQL query is to find the "most recent row, per group". For example, the following query returns the most recent `balance` per `user`:

```
SELECT user, date, balance
FROM balances t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT user, max(date) as most_recent_date
    FROM balances
    GROUP BY user
) t2
    ON t1.user=t2.user AND t1.date=t2.most_recent_date
```

How would we do this with the Diesel (version 2) ORM? It doesn't have to be a literal translation of the SQL query, just needs to functionally do the same thing. I've tried creating the equivalent of a "subquery":

```
let latest_row_per_group = balances::table
    .group_by(balances::user)
    .select((
        balances::user,
        diesel::dsl::max(balances::date),
    ));
```

but I'm not able to join this to the original table, because it's a `SelectStatement` type, not actually a table.

Would love to avoid writing raw SQL here if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Diesel's built-in DSL does currently not support joins to subqueries. You can extend the DSL in a third party crate. The [Extending Diesel](https://diesel.rs/guides/extending-diesel.html) guide contains an example for that, although for a slightly different query.